# How to do elegant exception handling while retaining JavaScript debugger capabitilities

Tags: javascript, debugging, exception, firebug

You know JavaScript can basically throw any object or even primitive as an exception:

```
throw 1;
throw { text: "hello" }
```

Sadly, debuggers like Firefox will log exceptions to console including a link to the code line where the exception was thrown if we throw built-in `Error` object.

In order to solve that limitation I thought: why don't I override `toString` and I give an exception instance as argument of `Error` constructor so exception will be implicitly converted to `string`?

```
var ArgumentException = function(args) {
   this._argName= args.argName;
}

ArgumentException.prototype = {
    _argName: null,

    get argName() { return this._argName; },

    toString: function() { 
       return "ArgumentException was thrown. Affected argument: " + this.argName;
    }
};

throw Error(new ArgumentException({ argName: "someArgument" }));
```

Obviously, above code listing is a simplification of a real-world case.

Ok, this works and solve the whole problem.

But this kills the purpose of using exceptions since a `try/catch` won't be able of handling exceptions by type:

```
try
{
    throw Error(new ArgumentException({ argName: "someArgument" }));
} catch(e) {
    if(e instanceof ArgumentException) {
         // This will happen never! "e" will hold a Error instance!!!!
    }
}
```

**How do you solve this problem?** In fact, it's something with Web browser's debugger rather than a problem with actual JavaScript, but as debugging is an important point in any development cycle, it should be took seriously.

Thank you in advance.

#### EDIT

I want to share my other conclusion:

```
try
{
    debugger;
    throw new ArgumentException({ argName: "someArgument" });
} catch(e) {
    if(e instanceof ArgumentException) {

    }
}
```

Above solution will log the exception to the debugger console, but it'll stop the debugger before it's ever thrown. Ok, you don't get the link to the exact line but the debugger gets stopped there so you can know where the exception is going to be thrown.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `ArgumentException` with `Error`?

Comment: @PaulS. You'll need to read my question again!! I explained that in my question :D

Comment: @PaulS. Maybe I can add some info: that logs an error to console with the exception message while retaining the link to where the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make your exception inherit from *Error*?

```
function ArgumentException(data) {
    this.name = "ArgumentException";
    this.message = arguments.length ? 'Affected argument: ' + data.argName : "Illegal argument";
}
// set up inheritance
ArgumentException.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
ArgumentException.prototype.constructor = ArgumentException;

// use it 
try {
    throw new ArgumentException({argName: "someArgument"});
} catch(e) {
    if(e instanceof ArgumentException) {
        console.log(e); // hi there
    }
}
// see it normally
throw new ArgumentException({argName: "someOtherArgument"});
// ArgumentException: Affected argument: someOtherArgument
```

For more, look at [Custom Error Types on **MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types)

Comment: I've not tried `Object.create` to inherit Error but using the `new` operator. Let me make a jsFiddle and try your approach. It sounds fine!

Comment: Ok, you did it ;) `new` approach to inherit the Error prototype was a big failure because just doing `new Error()` throws the error. But `Object.create` doesn't have this problem. Nice @Paul S.! Thank you for your effort :)